# Combine multiple raw files into single parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I have a large number of events partitioned by yyyy/mm/dd/hh in S3.
Every partition has about 80.000 of raw text files.
Every raw file has about 1.000 Events in JSON format.

When I run the script to do my transformation:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=from_database,
                                                                table_name=from_table,
                                                                transformation_ctx="datasource0")
map0 = Map.apply(frame=datasource0, f=extract_data)
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(......)
applymapping1.toDF().write.mode('append').parquet(output_bucket, partitionBy=['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'])
```

I end up with a large number of small files across partitions named like:

```
part-00000-a5aa817d-482c-47d0-b804-81d793d3ac88.snappy.parquet
part-00001-a5aa817d-482c-47d0-b804-81d793d3ac88.snappy.parquet
part-00002-a5aa817d-482c-47d0-b804-81d793d3ac88.snappy.parquet
```

Each of them is 1-3KB in size. Number corresponds roughly to the number of raw files I have.

My impression was that the Glue will take all the events from catalog, partition them the way I want and store **in a single file** per partition.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to set `repartition(1)` which will shuffle the data from all partitions to a single partition which will generate a single output file while writing.

```
applymapping1.toDF()
             .repartition(1)
             .write
             .mode('append')
             .parquet(output_bucket, partitionBy=['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'])
```

Comment: Thank you! After a bit of reading I'm thinking *coalesce* is maybe more appropriate. Any thoughts?

Comment: coalesce(1) and repartition(1) are same in functionality as whole data has to be transferred in one partition there has to be a shuffle and it will be same for both the operations,

Comment: i know this is an old thread.. but for any passersby... while seemingly the same functionality, I have repeatedly found coalesce(1) to be non-performant on large-scale data, and resorted to repartition(1) if I really need a single file.

Comment: @Renée That is because repartition will force another shuffle (and therefore stage) to change the parallelism (number of partitions going into an extra added stage). On the other hand, coalesce changes the parallelism upstream (number of partitions going into the current stage); thus any data transformations in the stage containing a coalesce would have reduced parallelism. Which is faster between repartition and coalesce depends on the data and processing steps being performed (ie the extra shuffle from repartition may be the bottleneck). Sahil's comment is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think repartition(1) will do what is asked `create a single file per partition`.  repartition(1) will create 1 partition not one file per partition.